# how do i get webapp deployment information using AZ CLI

Tags: deployment, azure-cli

I am trying to get the app deployment information from a webapp using az cli

basically this info that i can get from AZ portal deployment center, but i am trying to get this using az cli:

[image]

information i am trying to get is:

Branch, build and release, with date of deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ***az webapp deployment module*** you can configure the ***CI/CD*** of the webapp but ***there is no command to list the deployments from CLI*** . So , after looking into ***[resources.azure.com](http://resources.azure.com)*** , Found that the Deployment details can be received from ***[`Azure Rest Api's`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/get-deployment)***.

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroupName>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<WebAppName>/deployments?api-version=2020-12-01
```

***Example:***

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you AnsumanBal-MT, you have confirmed my findings as well. 
using Azure Rest Api was the only way i found to query deployment info.  with a slight difference, i am exporting the template (which also has that info) and searching for "active" status of the deployment. 
basically using this request:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resource-groups/export-template

Comment: glad to be of help @Vital